# Why many official helm charts include Passwords/Credentials in Values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I noticed that many official charts hosted on Google or Bitnami repositories are including Username/Password/Credentials in the Values file, **without giving you the ability to use an existing secret**.

Can you helm me understand what would be the reason behind such approach?

As far as I know, including clear credentials in helm charts is not a best-practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's quicker and it will work out of the box.

If you try to use the already existing `secret`, it has to be in the same namespace as the `deployment`. If it's not then it has to be copied and validate if it was moved correctly.

You should not rely on unchanged charts in production environment, as @[switchboard.op](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10615691/switchboard-op) mentioned.

I think most apps that are being rewritten for [GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy) are using secrets.

Answer (score 1):

I think the maintainers expect you to override those default values when you create a release for something that's worth protecting. You can do this with your own values file or with the `--set` runtime flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good practice, however as mentioned by @Crou, it's quick. In general, I think each Helm Chart should give an option to define your credentials as secrets.

We do it in the Hazelcast Helm Charts by giving [this option](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/c00d878e7fc76189138341ff9e6787179853755e/stable/hazelcast/values.yaml#L190). I think that's the best-practice for Helm Charts.